# Can't play any Flash videos

Tags: video, flash, lubuntu, video-player, codecs

Recently installed Lubuntu 12.04 with alternate installer on Compaq Evo N400c (850Mhz PIII, 20GB ATA HDD, 512MB RAM).

After installation of  restricted extras and medibuntu codecs I realized that it can't play videos. I tried Midori, Firefox, Chrome, Chromium but all the browsers say: "Shockwave plugin cannot opened...." I tried Adobe plugin, no succes. I tried Gnash, a little success because it plays the videos but it is too slow, cannot enjoy the videos!

I downloaded the FLV file but I could not play it with VLC/gnome player etc.

Any Idea?

Comment: Is it happening on a certain video or every video? can you play other videos such as .wmv or something?

Comment: Have your restart after install [Lubuntu Restricted Extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lubuntu-restricted-extras/) ?

Comment: So i can play any videos, my problem is in browsers!! And yes i restarted it at least 9000 times since the LRExtras installed

Comment: 9000 times? Geesh dude your computer is going to blow up if you restart it one more time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is the solution:

1. step make sure that flash-player is installed, if it's not than here's the code:

   `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`
2. Download an older release of Adobe flash player!

[Archive of Older versions](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)

Extract the archive and search the libflashplayer.so file! If you found that, than `gksu nautilus` (if you are using Lubuntu: `gksu pcmanfm`)

Go to the /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/ Folder and replace the libflashplayer.so

Now you are able to use the Flashplayer in any browser! (I used the 10.x.x version of Flash player)

Don't forget to lock the Version in Synaptic Software Center!